# Doctrine and Mongodb: Remove all documents with field not in array

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to remove all documents with a field not in an array of ids that I have. When I try, it just removes everything from my database.

This is the code I have:

```
public function removeNotInListingIdList($ids, $country) {
      $dm = $this->getDocumentManager();
      $dm->createQueryBuilder('DnDReactivePandoraBundle:Property')
        ->remove()
        ->field('listingId')->notIn($ids)
        ->field('country', $country)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
  }
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

This is the output of the *debug* instruction:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 3
    [query] => Array
        (
            [listingId] => Array
                (
                    [$nin] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 15-77
                            [1] => 15-79
                            [2] => 15-82
                            [3] => 13-39
                            [4] => 15-85
                            [5] => 15-86
                            [6] => 15-60
                            [7] => 15-61
                            [8] => 16-8
                        )

                )

            [country] => Mexico
        )

    [newObj] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: `->field('country', $country)` is not valid, you should use `->field('country')->equals($country)`. Also if that's not the only problem exchange `->execute()` with `->debug()` and paste the results here (the query will not be executed but you'll get query that will be passed to driver)

Comment: Thanks @malarzm I just exchanged execute for debug and pasted the result.

Comment: Hmm given `listingId`s in your database are normal values it should work just fine... have you tried putting the query together on your own in mongo's shell?

Comment: I'm trying that right now

Comment: @malarzm I think it might have to do with the fact that I'm not using the mongo $and operator

Comment: `$and` is the default operator so it's not needed to use it explicitly :)

Answer (score 2):

You field country is not constructed properly. It should be:

```
   $dm = $this->getDocumentManager();
   $dm->createQueryBuilder('DnDReactivePandoraBundle:Property')
      ->remove()
      ->field('listingId')->notIn($ids)
      ->field('country')->equals($country)
      ->getQuery()
      ->execute();
```